# What is best practice to send single parameter name multiple times in HTTP GET Request (status=Saved&status=Published)?

Tags: rest, get, query-string, request-mapping, get-mapping

This is total new module to be added in our application.

In Get Request, End user requires data on basis of status Saved as well as Published.
The designer suggest to send status like below:

```
posts?status=Saved&status=Published&_sort=date&_order=asc
```

The above URL **does not appears extendable** as if user require data on 5 statuses in future it will keep n adding status& . (I need to write Spring Boot request mapping accordingly)

Could anyone who worked extensively on Rest API more better way to fix this approach as i think Post Request is of no use here as user is getting the data?

**Edit**: Also i am not sure if using _ (underscore) is fine?

Comment: Why shouldn't the "multiple occurrences of the same parameter name" approach work? https://medium.com/@AADota/spring-passing-list-and-array-of-values-as-url-parameters-1ed9bbdf0cb2

Comment: @Smutje: There are 10 Statuses in database so will it not create any problem to have big URL or alternative to this??

Comment: "What Is the Maximum Length of a URL?
Technically speaking, your URL should never be longer than 2,048 characters. Any long than this and Internet Explorer won’t be able to load your page."

Comment: @Smutje: So in that case we need to have Post Request in which we get Data?

Comment: In what case do you need what? Don't try to think of any possibility, solve actual problems

Comment: @Smutje
Just use case if URL getting big due to multiple statuses (of course not 2048 as of now in my case), then we should use POST in place of GET to send data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202394/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-smutje).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the statuses like below. I prefer to send one character status (S=saved, P=published) to controller as it is short and neat.

`posts?status=S,P&_sort=date&_order=asc`

and map statuses to a List in controller like below

```
@RequestParam List<String> status
```